# Книги для изучения ооп

Tags: ооп

Доброе время суток. Посоветуйте хорошие книги для изучение ооп.заранее спасибо.

Comment: английским языком владеете?

Comment: Да , на уровне чтения справляюсь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Основные понятия ООП](https://megamozg.ru/post/6908/) [статья]
2. [Объектно-ориентированное конструирование программных систем](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2336754/) [книга]
3. [Шаблоны проектирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) [wiki с примерами на различных языках]